# The summary for CheeseMod2 was not provided. How can I find the estimated regression equation for CheeseMod2 using anova output from R only?

Tags: r, regression

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to statistic and I really don't know how to approach this question

Comment: Your question is not very clear but let me say that you can't derive the estimated regression coefficients from ANOVA output.

Comment: One way to obtain some intuition for @Roland's assertion is to consider how the ANOVA output and regression equation might change if you were to change the units of measurement of an explanatory variable. For instance, if all the values of `H2S` were multiplied by 1000, then (a) its coefficient in the regression would merely be divided by 1000 to compensate and, because that results in exactly the same fit as before, (b) the ANOVA table would not change in the least. Consequently, the only conclusion about the regression coefficients you can derive from this output is they are all nonzero.

Comment: Thank you all for the input! The actual question given was vague. But now I understand more information would be needed to derive the equation.